# Call to smart contract method on Polygon reverts for unclear reasons

Tags: erc-721, polygon

Here are the relevant bits of my smart contract for context:

```
contract MyNFT3 is ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;
    string private _baseTokenURI;

    struct NFTData {
        string name;
        uint256 id;
        uint256 rarity;
        string tokenURI;
        uint256 XP;
    }

function mintNFT(address to, string memory name, uint256 id, uint256 rarity, string memory tokenURI) public onlyOwner {
        require(bytes(name).length > 0, "Name must not be empty");
        require(rarity > 0, "Rarity must be greater than 0");

        _tokenIdCounter = _tokenIdCounter + 1;
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIdCounter;

        _safeMint(to, newTokenId);
        NFTData storage data = _tokenData[newTokenId];
        data.name = name;
        data.id = id;
        data.rarity = rarity;
        data.tokenURI = tokenURI;
        data.XP = 0;
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);
    }

    ...

    function addXP(uint256 tokenId, uint256 xpAmount) public {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "Token ID does not exist");
        NFTData storage data = _tokenData[tokenId];
        data.XP += xpAmount;
    }

    ...

}
```

I'm calling it from a Javascript script as follow (again only including relevant code):

```
const myNFT = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
const data = myNFT.methods.addXP(tokenId, xpAmount).encodeABI();

const transactionParameters = {
      from: account.address,
      to: contractAddress,
      data: data,
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(600000)
    };

const signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transactionParameters, privateKey);
const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
```

The contract also has a `mintNFT` method which I'm able to call without any problems with similar Javascript code as above. But when it comes to calling `addXP`, I systematically get a revert:

```
Transaction reverted: reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xc45f87dee91f8ad69a163443020301a4c6afb19f53f7ec8fa59197a2607ef44a",
  "blockNumber": 33348531,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 629396,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 1500000016,
  "from": "0xa33fdc714738912943d42b0bbd5258835dfa3017",
  "gasUsed": 21070,
  "logs": [
    {
      "address": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010",
      "topics": [
        "0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010",
        "0x000000000000000000000000a33fdc714738912943d42b0bbd5258835dfa3017",
        "0x0000000000000000000000003a22c8bc68e98b0faf40f349dd2b2890fae01484"
      ],
      "data": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001cbe9ccc52000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d18893ddc06b3fb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043934190125156885610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d186c7f3f3a61fb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043934191de3b234d761",
      "blockNumber": 33348531,
      "transactionHash": "0x1805911186a13f510d5be15f1c3a030337cf70910a410148b3ad6b346fab34a0",
      "transactionIndex": 9,
      "blockHash": "0xc45f87dee91f8ad69a163443020301a4c6afb19f53f7ec8fa59197a2607ef44a",
      "logIndex": 21,
      "removed": false,
      "id": "log_5dec484a"
    }
  ],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004008000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000200000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000001000000000100000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0xce090daae459f8510f064c57a137bb34381e0c06",
  "transactionHash": "0x1805911186a13f510d5be15f1c3a030337cf70910a410148b3ad6b346fab34a0",
  "transactionIndex": 9,
  "type": "0x0"
}
```

I would really appreciate any pointers to fix this. Generally speaking I find it very difficult to debug these kind of issues (the error message is very obscure) and welcome any tips to help debugging better in the future!

Comment: My guess is that either the `require` fails or there is no item for the `tokenId`. You can for example comment out the require to see if that helps. Note that the require is using different logic to check the existence than the row after it uses for retrieving the data.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen thanks! Wouldn't I see the error message of the `require` in the outputs if the `require` was failing, like `"Token ID does not exist"`?
I added the `mintNFT` definition in my original post, to show how I'm storing the data. Do you see an issue with the way I retrive it in `addXP`?

Comment: can you verify your contract on polygonscan ?